# firewall-cmd doesn't work when called through OpenVPN connection, why not?

Tags: ssh, centos, openvpn, firewalld

I recently set up OpenVPN to run on a remote CentOS 7 server.  Once I establish an OpenVPN connection to the remote server from my local machine, I am able to `ssh` through the VPN tunnel with `ssh username@10.8.0.?`.  I can then run various commands on the remote machine (like `cd`, `nano`, etc.), all shielded by the VPN.  But when I try to run `firewall-cmd`, I get an error and am not able to configure the firewall. Why is this?  And **what can I change so that I can configure the firewall from within my OpenVPN-encrypted ssh session?**

For example, when I typed `firewall-cmd --list-all`, the terminal replied with:

```
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.4:/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.2637" (uid=1000 pid=22130 comm="/usr/bin/python -Es /usr/bin/firewall-cmd --list-a") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0 pid=728 comm="/usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork -")
Error: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.2637" (uid=1000 pid=22130 comm="/usr/bin/python -Es /usr/bin/firewall-cmd --list-a") interface="org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" member="getDefaultZone" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0 pid=728 comm="/usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork -")
```

Note that when I `ssh` to the same server from outside the VPN tunnel, I am able to successfully configure the firewall with `firewall-cmd`.  But I want to block access to `ssh` from outside the VPN, so I need to get `ssh` to work through the VPN.

Comment: you have to do it as root user.

Comment: @taliezin Why is that?

Comment: at least it uses iptables and root can do it. I think you can try with sudo you can do it: sudo firewall-cmd --list-all